# podman on windows WLS2 run containers always listen to 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, podman

I have installed the podman desktop on windows, with WLS2 version：

1. podman-machine-default

I try to run containers by `podman run` command or using podman-compose. Although the containers are listening to the 0.0.0.0, but I cannot access the services from other devies, or even on the same machine wiht machine ip and port.
When I use command `netstat -ano` to check the service listening status, it shows that the service is listening to 127.0.0.1.
But if I go to podman machine by command `podman machine ssh` and show service by `netstat -tupln`, the services are listening to the 0.0.0.0.

Therefore, I think there is something wrong with the machanizm between WLS2 and Podman? And how can I fix it?

My Environment is following:

1. Windows 21H2 19044.2965
2. podman desktop v1.0.1

WSL Version： 1.2.5.0
Kernal Version： 5.15.90.1
WSLg Version： 1.0.51
MSRDC Version： 1.2.3770
Direct3D Version： 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore Version： 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp

I tried to start up the containers by `podman run` command, and start the containers by podman compose. But although the container it self is listening to 0.0.0.0, but on windows the service is listening to 127.0.0.1.

I also tried to create a pod and move the containers into pod, with command 'podman pod create' and 'podman-compose -p new_pod_name', but still not work.